# Add Webpart on default.aspx using C#

Tags: development, web-part

I want to add a Custom Webpart on default.aspx.
The Web Part appears on the page but not on the right place. I want the webpart on the right site and on the first place.
I´m using the following Code to perform this action.

```
using (
            SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager =
                adminweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(adminweb.Url + "/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
byte[] kennzahlenWebPart = Resources.Kennzahlen;
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(kennzahlenWebPart);
XmlReader oxmlReader = new XmlTextReader(memory);
string errorMsg;
WebPart oWebPart = webPartManager.ImportWebPart(oxmlReader, out errorMsg);
webPartManager.AddWebPart(oWebPart, "Right", 0);
webPartManager.SaveChanges(oWebPart);
```

}

After that Code the Webpart always appears on the right site on the last place. I don´t know how to solve this issue.
Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try changing `webPartManager.AddWebPart(oWebPart, "Right", 0);` to `webPartManager.AddWebPart(oWebPart, "Right", 1);` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed it and now it is working.

Comment: I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `webPartManager.AddWebPart(oWebPart, "Right", 0);` to `webPartManager.AddWebPart(oWebPart, "Right", 1);` and it should work. I faced a similar issue some time back, I have blogged about it here [Web Parts not adding in proper order](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-web-parts-not-adding-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the webpart zone by changing the following line of your code

> webPartManager.AddWebPart(oWebPart, "Right", 0);

you can change it as per your requirement i.e Left, etc.

**EDIT**

Try something like this

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        using(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            YourWebPart webpart = new YourWebPart();
            webpart.ZoneID = "Top";
            webpart.Title = "My Webpart";
            wpManager.AddWebPart(webpart,"Top" , 0);
        }
    }
}
```

you can refer to [this link](http://www.stefangordon.com/add-web-part-to-page-programmatically/) too

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not work for me.

Comment: what did you used in place of "Right"?